# Enable/Disable SwaggerUI in runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am having 4 environment Development, Test, Staging, and Production.

We have to disable the Swagger for the Production environment only, but this should be configurable like if we want, we can enable it as well if in case to test some endpoint without building the application again.

This enabling and disabling of Swagger should be done on a runtime basis, as I mentioned I don't want to build the application again.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Add a config setting and enable Swagger only if the setting is set?

Comment: By default, the Configuration middleware will monitor and reload changes made to the appsettings.*.json files. To get their values without restarting the application you need to use the Options middleware and `IOptionsMonitor` instead of `IOptions` or `IOptionsSnapshot` to access the config value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Having configuration reload won't help you because you can't reconfigure the middleware pipeline in runtime (without restarting the app). You need to use `app.MapWhen` or `app.UseWhen` to access the most recent configuration.

Comment: @abdusco that's still `at runtime`. At runtime doesn't mean `without restarting the app`. There are many degrees of `at runtime`. Using `MapWhen` may not be necessary. And even there, it's better to use `IOptionsMonitor` than a custom service - or not.  The OP mentioned `Azure API Management` in a comment, which means the question isn't just about enabling Swagger

Answer (score 4):

Although @Ryan.Bartsch's answer is a valid approach, it misses a key point: `Startup.Configure` method is executed once at boot. When you change a configuration, `IOptionsMonitor` *will* reflect the changes, but as `Configure` method isn't executed again, the middleware pipeline will stay immutable. You have to restart the app to reconfigure the middleware.

To change the middleware at runtime, you can use `IApplicationBuilder.UseWhen` and optionally enable Swagger middleware. This lets you use any service or plain old `IConfiguration` (or `IOptionsSnapshot`) to decide when to enable Swagger.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline):

> `MapWhen` branches the request pipeline based on the result of the given predicate. Any predicate of type `Func<HttpContext, bool>` can be used to map requests to a new branch of the pipeline. ...
>
> `UseWhen` also branches the request pipeline based on the result of the given predicate. Unlike with `MapWhen`, this branch is rejoined to the main pipeline if it doesn't short-circuit or contain a terminal middleware.

```cs
// remove default middleware
// app.UseSwagger(/*...*/);
// app.UseSwaggerUI(/*...*/);

app.UseWhen(context =>
{
    var swaggerToggle = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SwaggerToggle>();
    var env = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
    // enable swagger only in some cases, use a service, IConfiguration, ... anything, really.
    return env.IsDevelopment() || swaggerToggle.IsEnabled;
}, builder => builder.UseSwagger(/*...*/).UseSwaggerUI(/*...*/));

// ... other middleware
```

An example implementation of `SwaggerToggle` could be as follows:

```cs
public class SwaggerToggle
{
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}

// register the service as singleton
services.AddSingleton<SwaggerToggle>();
```

Then it can be controlled via an endpoint

```cs
public class SwaggerToggleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SwaggerToggle _swaggerToggle;

    public SwaggerToggleController(SwaggerToggle swaggerToggle)
    {
        _swaggerToggle = swaggerToggle;
    }
    
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Toggle(bool enabled)
    {
        _swaggerToggle.IsEnabled = enabled;
        return Ok(new { enabled });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I control this with configuration e.g. in `appsettings.json`.

```
{
   "applicationSettings": {
      "serviceName": "Test",
      "swaggerUIEnabled": true
   }
}
```

And then configure `Startup.cs` as follows using [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore):

```cs
public class Startup
{
   private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      _configuration = configuration;
   }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      services.AddSettings<ApplicationSettings>(_configuration.GetSection("applicationSettings"));

      // ...

      if (appSettings.SwaggerUIEnabled)
      {
         services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
         {
            c.SwaggerDoc(appSettings.ServiceName,
               new OpenApiInfo
               {
                  Title = appSettings.ServiceName,
                  Version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?
                     .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
                     .InformationalVersion ?? "NA"
               });
         });
      }

      // ...
   }

   public static void Configure(
      IApplicationBuilder app,
      IServiceProvider provider)
   {
      // ...

      if (appSettings.SwaggerUIEnabled)
      {
         app.UseStaticFiles()
            .UseSwagger()
            .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
               c.SwaggerEndpoint(Url.Combine("/", "swagger.json"), appSettings.ServiceName);
            });
      }

      // ...
   }
}
```

the `swaggerUIEnabled` config setting will be `true` in all non-prod environments and `false` in prod.

Note: you'll need to host your Open API spec (`swagger.json` in code example above) statically under `wwwroot`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But I have already done this and this will require building the application again which I do not want to do. This enabling and disabling the SwaggerUI should be done at runtime without building the application.

Comment: If you host your app in Azure and use Azure App Config, you can use `IOptionsMonitor` or `IOptionsSnapshot` to update config dynamically at runtime. Alternatively you could have API gateway (e.g. Azure API Management) sitting in front of your application where you block requests (or return 404 or something) to the swagger UI.

Comment: @RohanNegi you don't need to recompile to change a setting in a config file. Tthat's the whole point of configuration settings. Just change the config file on the production server. You can even override it with an environment variable or command-line argument. In the default web host, env variables override file settings. You *have* to restart the application, unless you use the `IOptions` feature

Comment: Azure API Management can be used so that we can disable the Swagger related URLs

Comment: @RohanNegi what does an external service have to do with disabling your own service's endpoint? Did you want to ask a different question perhaps? How to restrict Swagger to specific clients, at specific times? Or control it through an external trusted service? It *matters*. You *can* add authorization, or restrict access. `at runtime` is a whole spectrum of choices, from settings affecting the entire web app, to feature toggles, to cookies/tokens affecting individual requests